# Reusing pipe data for different commands

Tags: shell, pipe, tee

I would like to use the same pipe for different applications, like in:

```
cat my_file | {
  cmd1
  cmd2
  cmd3
}
```

Cmd1 should consume part of the input. Cmd2 should consume another part and so on.

However, each cmd eats more of the input then it read really needs due buffering.

For example:

```
yes | nl | { 
  head -n 10 > /dev/null
  cat 
} | head -n 10
```

Outputs from line 912 instead of line 11.

Tee is not a good option, because each command is supposed to consume part of the stdin.

Is there a simple way to get this working?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is any general solution to this.  Ideally, commands should put back anything they read that they don't use but with pipes that is not always possible.  Even if they did you would have to trust the commands to do so - there's no way for the shell to enforce any such agreement.  For specific solutions you can come up with your own custom script to replace everything inside the `{ }`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll write some more functions avoiding buffering to replace head, tail and other commands.

Comment: Use `cat` in each script to flush `STDIN` and pass stream to `STDOUT`.

Comment: @jw013 There is no way for an application to put back a character. The input buffer is internal to the application: as far as the OS is concerned, the application has read the byte, whether it's processed it usefully or not.

Comment: @Gilles Not even reading one character at a time and using `ungetc()`?

Comment: @jw013 `ungetc()` pushes a character back to the input stream's buffer inside the application. It doesn't have any visible effect outside the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `tee` to duplicate command for processing whole stream by many command:

```
( ( seq 1 10 | tee /dev/fd/5 | sed s/^/line..\ / >&4 ) 5>&1 | wc -l ) 4>&1 
line.. 1
line.. 2
line.. 3
line.. 4
line.. 5
line.. 6
line.. 7
line.. 8
line.. 9
line.. 10
10
```

or split line by line, using bash:

```
while read line ;do
    echo cmd1 $line
    read line && echo cmd2 $line
    read line && echo cmd3 $line
  done < <(seq 1 10)
cmd1 1
cmd2 2
cmd3 3
cmd1 4
cmd2 5
cmd3 6
cmd1 7
cmd2 8
cmd3 9
cmd1 10
```

Finaly there is a way for running `cmd1`, `cmd2` and `cmd3` only once with 1/3 of stream as *STDIN*:

```
( ( ( seq 1 10 |
         tee /dev/fd/5 /dev/fd/6 |
           sed -ne '1{:a;p;N;N;N;s/^.*\n//;ta;}' |
           cmd1 >&4
     ) 5>&1 |
       sed -ne '2{:a;p;N;N;N;s/^.*\n//;ta;}' |
       cmd2 >&4
  ) 6>&1 |
    sed -ne '3{:a;p;N;N;N;s/^.*\n//;ta;}' |
    cmd3 >&4
) 4>&1 
command_1: 1
command_1: 4
command_1: 7
command_1: 10
Command-2: 2
Command-2: 5
Command-2: 8
command 3: 3
command 3: 6
command 3: 9
```

For trying this, you could use:

```
alias cmd1='sed -e "s/^/command_1: /"' \
    cmd2='sed -e "s/^/Command_2: /"' \
    cmd3='sed -e "s/^/Command_3: /"'
```

For using one stream on different process if on same script, you could do:

```
(
    for ((i=(RANDOM&7);i--;));do
        read line;
        echo CMD1 $line
      done
    for ((i=RANDOM&7;i--;));do
        read line
        echo CMD2 $line
      done
    while read line ;do
        echo CMD3 $line
      done
)
CMD1 1
CMD1 2
CMD1 3
CMD2 4
CMD2 5
CMD2 6
CMD2 7
CMD2 8
CMD2 9
CMD3 10
```

For this, you may have to transform your separated scripts into *bash function* to be able to build one overall script.

Another way could be to ensure each script won't output anything to *STDOUT*, than add a `cat` at end of each script to be able to *chain* them:

```
#!/bin/sh

for ((i=1;1<n;i++));do
   read line
   pRoCeSS the $line
   echo >output_log
 done

cat
```

Final command could look like:

```
seq 1 10 | cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd2
```

Comment: I don't think this answers what the OP is trying to do.  The idea is for sequential commands to each consume a portion of the same pipe stream, each picking up exactly where the previous one left off.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is a bit different of your script. I would like, for example, cmd1 processing the first 10 lines, cmd2 processing the next 15 lines, and so on. Cmd1, cmd2, etc are bash functions, and these functions decide the number of lines to be processed according to the input.

Comment: @arnaldocan Ok, I think rightly understand the need, look the sample script and last command sample.

Comment: I think the fourth example solves the problem. Is there any way to avoid using "read" because of its speed limitations on large files?

Comment: You may use `mapfile -n $numLines arraOfLines`

Answer (score 2):

For `head -n 10` to be able to read 10 lines and not a single more character from the pipe on stdin, it would have to read one character at a time to be not read anything after the last newline character. That would be inefficient.

That's what the `read` shell builtin does when stdin is not seekable.

```
{
  head -n 10 > /dev/null
  cat
} < myfile
```

Works because `head` reads a chunk of data and `lseek`s back to just after the end of the 10th line. That obviously can't be done with pipes.

On recent GNU or FreeBSD systems, some applications that use `stdio` can be told to read their input one character at a time by using `stdbuf -i1` or `stdbuf -i0`.

However, that doesn't work with GNU `head`. It works with GNU `sed` though, so you could do:

```
seq 20 | {
  stdbuf -i0 sed -n 10q
  cat
}
```

Alternatively, what you could do is control what goes on a pipe so that there's ever at most only one line in it at a time.

For instance, on Linux, you could do:

```
one_line_at_a_time() {
  perl -MTime::HiRes=usleep -pe '
    BEGIN{$|=1;open F, "<", "/dev/fd/1"; $r=""; vec($r,fileno(F),1) = 1}
    usleep(1000) while select($ro=$r,undef,undef,0)'
}
seq 20 | one_line_at_a_time | { head -n 10 > /dev/null; cat; }
```

That `perl` script opens "/dev/fd/1" in read mode which on Linux causes the other end of the pipe connected to fd 1 (stdout) to be opened. That way, with `select`, it can check if there's something in the pipe (and sleep until it's been emptied) before sending the next line.

Of course, that's also terribly inefficient.